# In Swift, is it possible for a Objective-C class' properties to satisfy a Swift @obj protocol computed property requirement?

Tags: swift, objective-c-category, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

For instance, I want to extract a Swift protocol from my existing Objective-C class `MyFoo`.  Let's call this protocol `FooProtocol`.

The situation looks like this:

```
// In Objective-C
@interface MyFoo
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *foo;
@end
@implementation MyFoo
// ... -(instancetype)initWithString: is implemented here
@end

// In Swift
@objc protocol FooProtocol {
    var foo: String { get set }
}

extension MyFoo: FooProtocol {
    // do nothing here!
}
```

Then I should be allowed to do this:

```
let theFoo: FooProtocol = MyFoo(string: "Awesome")
NSLog("\(theFoo.foo)") // Prints awesome.
```

But I get told "MyFoo does not conform to protocol FooProtocol". Okay. Fair enough, I guess the protocol extension needs a little nudge:

```
extension MyFoo: FooProtocol {
    var foo: String! { get { return foo } set { NSLog("noop") }}
}
```

but I'm getting errors from the compiler that look like

```
Getter for 'foo' with Objective-C selector 'foo' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MyFoo` needs a base class, otherwise the Objective-C code does not compile. `let theFoo: Foo = ` should probably be `let theFoo: FooProtocol = `. – And then your code *does* compile in both Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 GM. – Is that your real code?

Comment: you are redeclaring class property in protocol extension. swift won't know which should be run

Comment: @MartinR thanks, I updated the question. No, it's not my real code. I'l need to set up a test project and try... surprising, because in my real project I did exactly that and I keep getting the error.

Comment: @fatuhoku: If your posted code does not exhibit the problem, how can anyone answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces have different signatures and therefore the compiler doesn't really know what to do.

Try this:

```
// In Objective-C
@interface MyFoo
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *foo;
@end
@implementation MyFoo
// ... -(instancetype)initWithString: is implemented here
@end

// In Swift
@objc protocol FooProtocol {
    var foo: NSString { get set }
}

extension MyFoo: FooProtocol {
    // do nothing here!
}
```